# PapaParse - Can't use data after parsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, csv, papaparse

Looking to use the data in a CSV to create a network graph. Kinda stuck at the first hurdle as I want to create an array of arrays from the CSV using PapaParse, however can't seem to push the data from papaParse into my array, all I get is an empty array returned in my console. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
var dirtyNodeData = [];
Papa.parse("http://example.com/tmp/csvfile.csv", {
    download: true,
    header: false,
    complete: function(results) {
        dirtyNodeData.push(results.data);
    }
});

console.log(dirtyNodeData);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Papa.parse` function is asynchronous, so you'll need to handle receiving data when you receive the data inside your `complete` function rather than just after calling `parse`. For example, you could do this:

```
var dirtyNodeData = [];
Papa.parse("http://example.com/tmp/csvfile.csv", {
    download: true,
    header: false,
    complete: function(results) {
        dirtyNodeData.push(results.data);
        console.log(dirtyNodeData);  
        }
    });
```

i.e. you can add handler code after you push the data into your array. You could also create another function called `postReceiveCSV()` which is called in place of the `console.log`, in which you can add anything you need to do after the data is successfully received.

If that isn't the issue, then check that the `results` object is what you expect.

Comment: Thanks, so basically if I want to use the data I have to use it inside a function called inside the "complete" callback, yes?

Comment: Yep, that's right. Only then do you know that the data has been received

Comment: its giving me file path instead of data